# AWS STS endpoint selection in CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When using STS to assume a role, in the AWS SDKs (Java, for example), we have shaved valuable seconds off the operation by selecting the 'local' STS endpoint for the region our code is executing in (e.g. https://sts.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com).

Is it possible to do the same from the CLI (`aws sts assume-role ...`?  There doesn't seem to be an option to override the default endpoint in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: [Activating and Deactivating AWS STS in an AWS Region](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_enable-regions.html) and enable the region endpoint you want to connect to.

**--region (string)**

is common for all AWS CLI commands. Once you enable additional endpoints, you can use `--region (string)` to override the default endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, STS is definitely active in our region, and we are already using the `--region` option, so sounds like we should already be connecting to the local STS service

Comment: Check CloudTrail to make sure you are connecting to the correct region.

Comment: Add the AWS CLI command line option --debug. The debug output will contain the endpoint used.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. totally forgot about --debug.